# Doctrine from Symfony ignoring part of my having clause?

Tags: sql, doctrine, symfony-1.4, having

I have the following code:

```
$sub_questions_no_restricted = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->select("q2.id")
                ->from("question q2")
                ->leftJoin("q2.CountryRestrictions cr2")
                ->groupBy("q2.id")
                ->having("count(cr2.country_iso)=0");
```

I want to get all questions ids that have no restrictions of country

But symfony doesn't generate a correct SQL, ignoring a part of the having clause.

Generated DQL and SQL are:

```
DQL=SELECT q2.id FROM question q2 LEFT JOIN q2.CountryRestrictions cr2 GROUP BY q2.id HAVING count(cr2.country_iso)=0
SQL=SELECT q.id AS q__id FROM question q LEFT JOIN country_restriction c ON q.id = c.question_id GROUP BY q.id HAVING count(c.country_iso)=)
```

SQL ignores "0", and adds an ")"

What i'm doing wrong?
Its a Doctrine Problem?
Any suggestions?

Comment: try ->having("count(cr2.country_iso)='0'");

Comment: Nop @bleuscyther , it translates into:
HAVING count(c3.id)='0) ) --> Ignoring the last ', any other suggestion?

Comment: try <1 instead of =0 or pass the number as a parameter; i will try the recreate the scenario to seee what's the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put space between ) and = in having clause.

```
$sub_questions_no_restricted = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->select("q2.id")
                ->from("question q2")
                ->leftJoin("q2.CountryRestrictions cr2")
                ->groupBy("q2.id")
                ->having("count(cr2.country_iso) = 0");
```

Comment: Thank you! it works!
But its a weird error, it must work without spaces. ;)

Comment: Looks kinda like bug to me